# Java: System.getenv("APPDATA") returns null, now what?

Tags: java, windows

I just found out that when a Java program is launched on Windows via "Run As..." (from the executable's context menu) as a different user, a call to `System.getenv("APPDATA")` will return `null`, rather than the usual application data folder.

Now, I'm kind of a noob when it comes to Windows folders and such, so my question is, how should I deal with this situation when my program has to be able to store its data somewhere in order to work correctly? More specifically, if `System.getenv("APPDATA")` returns `null`, am I even *allowed* to store any data at all, and if so, where? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about user.home `System.getProperty("user.home")`, does that return null too when doing `Run As`?

Comment: This is returns C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName> on my machine. Looks good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved my own problem using JNA:

```
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32Util.getFolderPath(int nFolder)
```

where `nFolder = 0x001a` for the application data folder and `nFolder = 0x001c` for the local application data folder. On Windows XP, the output is

> C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Application Data
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Local Settings\Application Data

Most importantly, this does not return `null` when the program is launched via `Run As`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are always allowed to store data. You can use [temp directory](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0484.html) to store you data. You can get temp directory by `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");`.

Comment: Not suitable for permanent storage between sessions (kind of what I want), but good idea nonetheless :)

Comment: @python dude: What are you saving in file?

Comment: A Lucene index and program preferences, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you set an environment variable in windows, I noticed that java doesn't pick it up until I restarted the OS.